# Log4j is showing internal log4j event logs on tomcat start up after upgrade

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I upgraded `Log4j` from `2.9.1` to `2.13.2`. After upgrade lot of unnecessary logs are being shown while starting `tomcat` server.

```
DEBUG StatusLogger Using ShutdownCallbackRegistry class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0.319733 seconds to load 239 plugins from ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@6d78f375

DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 46 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting LoggerContext[name=531f4093, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@144283f3]...
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration started for context[name=531f4093] at URI null (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@144283f3) with optional ClassLoader: null
INFO StatusLogger Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=531f4093'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=531f4093,component=StatusLogger'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=531f4093,component=ContextSelector'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=531f4093,component=Loggers,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=531f4093,component=Appenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=531f4093,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=531f4093,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=531f4093,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
```

How to trun of all of these loggings?

My `log4j` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>

        <!-- ********************** Concole **************************-->
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="OFF"/>
        </Console>
<!-- other file appenders and loggers-->
  <!-- ********************************* Root ************************************ -->
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="async_file"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="async_errors_file" level="WARN"/>
        </Root>

    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

I tried with `<Configuratin status="WARN/OFF">` but did not work.

I have following dependencies

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

Please suggest what is the fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Log4j` doc:

```
From log4j-2.9 onward, log4j2 will print all internal logging to the console 
if system property log4j2.debug is defined (with any or no value).
```

Check if you declare `-Dlog4j2.debug` or `-Dlog4j.debug` something like this. In my case, as they mentioned in doc it has no value and I changed it to `-Dlog4j.debug="ERROR"`. Now, issue resolved and no internal logs are being printed.

Comment: I don't have this option specified but still getting this output((

Answer (score 0):

-DLOG4J-LEVEL=INFO try with this

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.